# Looking for film about an invader of earth that eats energy

Tags: story-identification, movie, alien-invasion

This is a film that I saw on television sometime in the 1960s. It was about some kind of alien invasion that featured an enormous device that moved about the landscape "eating" energy and destroying things. The device had the appearance of a tall skyscraper (hundreds of feet tall) with four "legs" that moved up and down in some kind of energy field as it moved about on the earth's surface. On the top was something like an "antenna" with two arms. At the end of each arm was a solid shape, one a sphere and the other a cube. Or something like that. This antenna was the device's energy collector.

I don't remember anything about the plot, except that the people fighting against it sent an aircraft carrying an atomic bomb to try to destroy the device. I am not sure if the bomb actually got dropped and the device absorbed its energy, or if they realized it in time and stopped the bomber from completing its mission. I am also not sure about how the device was finally defeated, but it might have been stopped by overloading its energy collection capability in some way.

Does anyone recognize this flick?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is probably [*Kronos*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUSgVm.jpg) (1957).  Basically the plot is an alien robot comes to Earth to steal energy.  The robot does kind of look like a skyscraper with legs.

[image: The alien robot from Kronos]

Quoting relevant bits from the [plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronos_(film)#Plot) on Wikipedia:

> The two scientists, along with Vera Hunter, LabCentral's staff photographer and Gaskell's girlfriend, rush to Mexico. After their arrival, they see an enormous dome, glowing and steaming, appear on the ocean horizon. The next morning, on the beach outide their room, they find **a very tall machine has appeared, its four-legged body has two mobile antennae.**
>
> They use a small helicopter to land atop the machine, glimpsing its complex inner workings before being forced to leave and fly back to LabCentral when the machine begins to move. The possessed Dr. Eliot, using lists of power stations and atom-bomb arsenals around the world, telepathically directs the machine. Now named Kronos by the news media, it methodically **attacks power plants in Mexico, draining all their energy.** In doing so, Kronos grows larger, consuming more and more power as it moves from one power source to the next. Four Mexican Air Force fighter planes attack, but the ever-growing alien machine easily destroys them and continues on its rampage.
>
> Meanwhile, when Kronos is absorbing energy, Eliot is momentarily freed from the influence of the energy force controlling him. Eliot tells his returned colleagues that **Kronos is an energy accumulator, sent by an alien race that has exhausted its own natural resources; they have sent their giant machine to drain all the Earth's available power** and then return it to their dying world.
>
> On Eliot's recommendation, the United States Air Force sends a B-47 bomber to drop an atomic bomb on Kronos. **Gaskell warns the Air Force general in charge that an atomic explosion will simply supply the alien machine with more massive amounts of energy**. The general attempts to abort the mission, but Kronos, aware of the plan by way of Dr. Eliot's mind, magnetically draws the jet to crash into it, absorbing the bomb's nuclear blast. The alien machine, now grown to an immense size, appears unstoppable, harvesting all forms of energy at will.

The robot does have 2 antennae with different shapes on the ends:

[image: The head of the Kronos robot showing its two antennae]

Comment: Thanks! That has to be it. After seeing your answer, I found a trailer for the movie on YouTube. In my memory, the special effects seemed much better than this, though. I think my imagination supplied a certain amount of realism that the film didn't actually have! I'm 71 now, but I saw this on TV when I was 9 or 10 years old, and it held my imagination all these years.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ErOqYD-i3Q